# There is no pdfium.dll after building with "gn gen"

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build, ninja, pdfium

I'm learning to build [pdfium project](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/). Following [the instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#visual-studio) I get 57 dlls in my out\ directory. However I cannot find the pdfium.dll which is supposed to contain functions like `FPDFAvail_GetDocument(), FPDFBitmap_GetBuffer()` etc.

Could anyone of you share your successful experience with building pdfium library?

Answer (score 0):

Check the root folder for an x64 and x86 folder.

They will be in there - move then (in folders) to the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I used this [repo](https://github.com/bblanchon/pdfium-binaries) to build PDFium library dll. Apparently the issue was that the patches were not applying and I had to manually apply the patches to the relevant files and then the build was successful.

Hope this helped.